# Customizing a Community with CSS and HTML

Tags: visualforce, css

I need to customize a community with CSS, what is the best way to do this in Salesforce?

Comment: This question is covering a wide area.  You need to specify what kind of community and which template is being used. You can get good amount of details here. https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. I would recommend you to read the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_custom.htm)

You can use inline Styling, however, it is best recommended you upload a CSS file to your Static Resources.

in order to load your custom CSS, you will want to

> Use the  tag or static HTML to include your own style
>   sheet or styles.

as follows:

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.customCSS}" />
```